# Derivative and tangent line

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

$$
s(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x^{2}+1, & x<0 \\
x+2, & 0 \leq x<2 \\
x^{2}, & x \geq 2
\end{array}\right.
$$

a) In which points is the function derivable

b) If possible calculate $s'(1)$ and give the equation for the tangent for $y= s(x)$ when $x =1$

The attempt at the questions

a) Check if the three functions are derivable by computing $\lim x$ go towards $0$ and $2$. The functions do not get same answer, thus the function $s(x)$ is not derivable in the points $x=0$ and $x=2$ ?

Comment: Don't forget that after approximately ~24 hours you should select the best answer to your question by clicking the check mark button under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

a) you are correct here
b) As Emilio Novati stated a couple seconds ago the derivative is piecewise:
$$s'(x)=\begin{cases}
2x \qquad x<0\\
1\qquad 0<x<2\\
2x \qquad x>2
\end{cases}$$
Which is true. However, because $x=1$ falls into the 2nd condition, which is linear, and the tangent line of a line is just a line, at $s(1)$ the tangent line is $x+2$